# Redirecting user conditionally to next viewcontroller even if user deletes the app from phone?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Scenario:
User logs into the app on page1 (first ViewContoller) of the app. He goes to page2 (second ViewContoller). On page2, there is a "Yes" and "No" button. User pushes "Yes". He goes to page3 (third ViewContoller). After this, every time user comes back I want him to get redirected to page3 directly without seeing page2 even if user deletes the app from his phone and re-installs it back. Lory had kindly given me a hint how to implement this functionality using NSUserDefaults if user doesn't delete the app and I tried it and it worked:

[How do I conditionally select the next view controller to navigate to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344720/how-do-i-conditionally-select-the-next-view-controller-to-navigate-to/34345341#34345341)

Now what if user uninstalles the app from his phone? how could I make the app remember that the user has been there before and he should get redirected to page3 readily after page1?

Comment: If the user removes the app you can't do anything. The only way to solve this is to store the info on server.

Comment: I'm using Parse now. So, I guess a solution would be: after user pushes Yes for the first time, I should record this answer into Parse withe unique ObjectID. When user logs in to the app for the next times even if after re-installing the app, I'll do a query on the ObjectID and see if the answer Yes is already there or not? is that correct?

Comment: The question is how do you know which ObjectID is the one the user had before.

Comment: That's correct, I'm not sure how I would know which ObjectID belongs to the  user. Is there a way to know? Also, maybe another way is to grab the email address of the user at first login and see if it already exists or not in later logins. I really prefer if there was a way to know about the ObjectID though since I don't want to keep user's personal information on server.

Comment: Actually that's a good point. So,I have a facebook login with Parse for my app, the first time user logs in, an ObjectID gets created for him, I checked it and this ObjectID stays the same in the later logins. I even deleted the app from Xcode simulator and ran it again. There wasn't a new unique ObjectID created for the user and the same user appeared in Parse. So, I guess when I log in with facebook, Parse has a way to know that it's the same user as before becuse it didn't create a new ObjectID. But, how does parse know about that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to implement that and here it is. I use query8 to see if user has ever logged in before and recorded a yes or no answer in Parse or not. If there is no answer recorded from user i.e. *if yesorno?["yesno"] == nil*, then I let them go to page2. If user has recorded a yes or no answer and has not deleted the app yet I use *NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("usedSaidYes") == true* to check for that (I guess I don't need this part since I could go to parse and fetch information anyway, but I'm too lazy to change the code right now!), next, if user has recorded an answer "Yes" then deleted the app from his phone, and reinstalled it again, since I recorded his answer in Parse when he pushed the "Yes" button, now I can use the *else if yesorno?["yesno"] as! String == "yes"* section to see if user has some recorded answer already and redirect him to page3. Hope it will help someone someday!

```
        if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
            userName = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!
            print("1111111111111111111111")
            var query8 : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
            query8.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userName, block: { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                let yesorno = object
                if yesorno?["yesno"] == nil {
                    print("222222222222222222222")
                    let page2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2ViewController") as! page2ViewController
                    let page2Nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: page2)
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                    var window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
                    window?.rootViewController = page2Nav
                } else if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userSaidYes") == true {
                    print("3333333333333333333333333")
                    var page3ViewController: page3ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3ViewController") as! page3ViewController
                    self.presentViewController(page3ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else if yesorno?["yesno"] as! String == "yes" {
                    print("44444444444444444444444")
                    var page3ViewController: page3ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3ViewController") as! page3ViewController
                    self.presentViewController(page3ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
```